# retrofit can't do a sencond request for the same api

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I have a problem when I use retrofit+rxJava to refresh my page, the request can't be give out.

I mean, for same api, I can only request succeed at the first time. But, this did not appear in my previous project.

I don't know what happened, any one can help me, thanks a lot!

my api like this:

[image]

Comment: post your activity code from where you are calling the api

Comment: Please don't post picture instead of your code. Copy past directly your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found why was it occurred is that no matter what the responce type it is ,i all solved  the Responce white a Subscribe,when i use a real  Object type like Subscribe to replace  Subscribe,it worked.